# What is good symmetric (commutative) hash to combine two values?

Tags: hash

This question is about a pair of integers `A` and `B`, which should be hashed in a symmetric way. By symmetric I mean that:

```
hash(A,B) == hash(B,A)
```

`A` and `B` already are hashes of bigger data sets, but this does not change much about this question, I guess.

A poor idea would be:

```
hash(A,B) = A XOR B
```

A somewhat better approach is:

`hash(A,B) = (A NOT B) + prime_factor*(A AND B)`

Is there something even better (but still fast)?

Comment: `hash(A,B) = any_other_hash(min(A,B), max(A,B))`

Comment: @melpomene: nice answer, thanks :)